# Cannot create C# project in Visual Studio 2019 which can be debugged

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio I perform the following steps to create a new C# project

1. Create New Project
2. Console App (.Net Core) C#

The project is created with a valid Hello World C# file. But the Debug option is disable (greyed out).

Presumably this is related to the fact that '0 Projects' is displayed alongside the project in Solution Explorer.

I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio but this did not help

No error messages were displayed.

I am using Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0
The Visual Studio version is 16.3.1 - I did a clean install today
[Screen shot showing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAfzH.png)

Comment: could you add a screenshot of the '0 Projects' in Solution Explorer?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of what you're seeing in visual studio

Comment: If you recently  - like yesterday or today - updated VS, make sure you have dotnet core SDKs installed that work with VS2019. Also check if the "Use core preview" setting might need to be dis-/enabled with the SDKs you already have on the machine.

Comment: Given the major update to VS2019 that arrived yesterday: exactly which version of VS2019 do you have?

Comment: Try a clean build.

Comment: you need to have a solution (*.sln file) and a project (*.csproj) loaded if you want to debug. you can not open a cs-file and expect VisualStudio to guess what kind of project this is supposed to be and how to handle this

Comment: The solution (.sln file) and a project (.csproj) file exist - they appear when I switch to folder view.
It is not clear to me how I access the the "Use core preview" setting. If I select Tools --> Options --> Projects and Solutions --> - there is no option for .Net